# Is_search not working on search results page

Tags: search, conditional-tags

I have an extra submenu with this code in the sidebar:

```
if(is_404() || is_search()) :
    echo 'should be empty';
else :
    if($post->post_parent == '68')
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { 
        ?><ul><?php echo $children; ?></ul><?php 
    }
endif;
```

I have a problem with the first line. It's working fine on the 404 page and on the search page if you search for something that doesn't exist, but when you look for something that does exist, the submenu is popping up in the sidebar. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Where do you place this code?

Comment: I place it in sidebar.php

Comment: Don't hardcode post values. If you really must use 'magic' values, refer to post slugs instead

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is for the `else` to show up on 404 pages and on search pages *but only when* the search returns no results, the conditional you need is ...

```
if(is_404() || (is_search() && 0 === $wp_query->found_posts)) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

The difference between that and your code is that I added an additional check to see if the search query has any results. The brackets around `is_search() && 0 === $wp_query->found_posts)` make the `||` operate against the whole clause, just like brackets in math, really.

If you don't want the `else` on any search or 404 pages then you need...

```
if(!is_404() || !is_search()) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

... but that is what you have so I am unsure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, what I want is the menu NOT to show up on 404, search and search resultspage. Now it works fine with 404 and search page without results but when I get results de menu is back...

Comment: my problem is that `if(!is_404() || !is_search()) { ` is not working allways. It works fine on 404 and search if nothing found but it doesn't work on search page if there are results. I don't understand, it's like a bug.

Comment: I found the problem, it was part of another if/ else, excluding the 404 and search had to be earlier in the code. Thanks for al your responses!